# Column resizing in HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resizable

I have two tables. One for header and other for the body. I created it this way so that header will remain fixed if the body overflows.

```js
(function() {
    var target = $("#target");
    $("#source").scroll(function() {
        target.prop("scrollTop", this.scrollTop)
            .prop("scrollLeft", this.scrollLeft);
    });
})();
```

```css
.scroll-example {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
td:hover i {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  visibility: visible;
}
i {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="overflow: hidden;width: 400px;">
  <table id="target" class="scroll-example" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">HHHHHHHHHHHHH</td>
      <td class="col2">HHHHHHHHHHH</td>
      <td class="col3">HHHHHHHHHHH</td>
      <td class="col4">HHHHHHHHHHH</td>
      <td class="col5">HHHHHHHHHHH</td>
      <td class="col6">HHHHHHHHHHH</td>
      <td class="col7" width="20px" style="border-color: white;"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="source" class="scroll-example" style="overflow: scroll;height: 50px;">
    <tr>
      <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
      <td class="col2"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
      <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
      <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
      <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
      <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Now I am looking for resizing the columns dynamically. So when the user resizes the top table column it should resize the corresponding bottom cell column.

I tried `td{resize: horizontal;}` but it is not working and I guess that is because of `td{min-width:100px;max-width:100px;}`.

Is there a way to achieve the column resizing in this table?

I am a beginner with CSS and jQuery. It would be of great help if you could put an example code. Thanks you.

Sample:

I have dragged 'Account Name' column and when I release it, the column width is set.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve by your question. Please try clarifying it a bit so more people will have a chance to help you.

Comment: @Thatkookooguy I am looking for column widening and shrinking like you drag a column and expand its width.

Answer (score 1):

Ive searched a lot for my own table widget. You need 2 Tables in each of them a colgroup with col´s they have to match your table column count. Ive created a fiddle i hope it´s clear enough. The two col´s of the Tables needs to be synced on your jquery resize functionality.

```css
.head{
  
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    empty-cells: show;
  
}

.body{
  
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    empty-cells: show;
  
}
```

```html
<table class="head">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="100px"> <!-- Our resized column -->
        <col>
        <col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>From</td>
            <td>Subject</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="body">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="100px"> <!-- Our resized column -->
        <col>
        <col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>00001</td>
            <td>Mister Exmple</td>
            <td>Problems with sharing</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>00002</td>
            <td>Mister Example 02</td>
            <td>Ouh is this a subject?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>00003</td>
            <td>Mistr Default</td>
            <td>Yo whats up</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am not able to expand width of any column. Can you please share the fiddle link?

Comment: This functionality is not implemented yet in this snippet its only a help to get forward. You need to modify the width of a column i.e with a drag handle on the td of the table head. For the moment its not possible for me to build the fiddle with full functionality sorry.